# How to get all configurable product which use specific attribute?

Tags: php, magento

I want all configurable product which use size_variation attribute and size_variation attribute type is drop down.

Please help me.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Can please try the below code...

```
     $attribute_code = "size";
            $attribute_details = Mage::getSingleton("eav/config")->getAttribute('catalog_product', $attribute_code);
            $attributeId = $attribute_details->getId(); // ret
    //92 is attribute 
            $collection=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addFieldToFilter('type_id', 'configurable'); 
$collection->getSelect()->join( array('config'=> 'catalog_product_super_attribute'), 'config.product_id = e.entity_id and config.attribute_id=92', array('product_id'));        
$collection->load();
echo count($collection);
foreach($collection as $pro){
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($pro->getName());
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
 $category_id = 4;

$catagory_model = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category_id); //where $category_id is the id of the category
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1)->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', array(2, 4)); //only enabled product
$collection->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'url', 'small_image')); //add product attribute to be fetched
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', 'configurable');
$collection->addStoreFilter();
//$collection->load(true, true); // first parameter show sql query in output, second show sql query in var/log/syslog


if (!empty($collection)) {
    foreach ($collection as $_product):
        echo $_product->getName();
        //echo get_class($this);
        ?>
            <ul><li class="cell-enable a-center"><input type="checkbox" <input type="checkbox" value="new_slider" name="drives[]"><a><img width="40" height="40" onmouseout="productPreviewHide();" onmouseover="productPreview('<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(165, 165); ?>');" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>" src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(50, 50); ?>"></a></li>
                
            </ul>
        <?php
    endforeach;
}
```

Size_variation is not for a single attriute set. We can filter the product based on the attribute sets. To get only the "shoe_size" attribute sets, add ID of that particular attribute set. See the below code.

```
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('attribute_set_id', 40);
```

Add the above link next to the `$collection->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'url', 'small_image'));`  Now you can see only the products which contain the attribute_set_id as 40. 40 is the ID of attribute-set for **Shoes** . First check what are the attribute sets that you need and collect those ID of it and place them in an array of select query. IF you need only single attribute set then array is not required...

Comment: its not working,i want all configurable product from attribute id or name

Comment: You have to modify the code as per your requirement. Just copy paste will not give your required answer. You need to add your required attribtues to the select filter.